# How can I map an entity in an XML file to another entity in the same XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file which is structured as follows:

```
<data>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <name>
            <birthday>
        </person>
        <person>
            ...
        </person>
    </persons>
    <tickets>
        <ticket>
            <person_id>
            <speed>
        </ticket>
    </tickets>
<data>
```

A person can have several tickets, whereby the person_id indicates to which person the ticket should be assigned. Now I would like to display the corresponding tickets for each person with the help of XSLT. My transform.xsl file, in which I have already written pseudo code, looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>XML to HTML</title>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        </head>
        
        <body>
            <div>
                <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Birthday</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="data/persons/person">
                        <xsl:sort select="name"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="birthday"/></td>
                        </tr><
                        PSEUDO:
                        for i in length(tickets):
                            if ticket[i].person_id == person.index:
                                display ticket[i]
                        END PSEUDO
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I look forward to any answers!

Comment: It's not clear what ties a person to a ticket (there is no  `id` or `index` node in `person`). In general, you want to use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to resolve cross-references. Please provide a [mcve] showing a representative example of the input XML as well as the exact expected output.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
<xsl:variable name="person_id" select="position()"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/tickets/ticket[person_id=$person_id]"/>
```

Then add the ticket template to display each ticket :

```
<xsl:template match="ticket">
    <tr><td>Speed : <xsl:value-of select="speed"/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If a ticket's `person_id` refers to the person's position, then this is not going to work if the persons are being sorted as shown.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately I am not allowed to have this statement "<xsl:template match="ticket">" inside my for-each loop...

Comment: @Ben : the template must be after your template.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : you are right.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is the "key" function. The solution to my problem is something like that:

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/persons/person">
    <xsl:sort select="name"/>                                     
        <b><xsl:value-of select="name"/></b>
            <p>
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('my_key',$pos)">
                        person_id: <xsl:value-of select="person_id"/>
                        Speed: <xsl:value-of select="speed"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    Amount of tickets: <xsl:value-of select="count(key('my_key',$pos))"/>
            </p>
        <b><xsl:value-of select="birthday"/></b>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: adding some explanations is certainly a good thing !